# JQuery - How to clone or repeat image based on user entered input

Tags: javascript, jquery

In plain javascript I can get an image to repeat based on user input. Pop is a variable holding the image, and totalTreats is a variable holding a user entered number:

```
document.getElementById('treats').innerHTML = pop.repeat(totalTreats);
```

I need to use jQuery, and can't get it to work using:

```
$('#treats').append($pop).clone($totalTreats);
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. What is `$pop`? What is `$totalTreats`? And if your first snippet works why do you need to convert it to jQuery?

Comment: Your question contains an answer. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: The equivalent jQuery version is: `$('#treats').html(pop.repeat(totalTreats));`

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop. I'm assuming $pop is some existing element.

```
for(let i=0;i<$totalRepeat);i++){
    $('#treats').append($pop.clone());
}
```